# Traversing Through a 2D Array diagonally from all sides

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, traversal, diagonal, n-queens

I'm currently working on N Queens problem where the input will be the size of the 2D array and the actual values of the 2D array. This code will check wether or not this input is valid, as in there aren't any other queens attacking each other, or if its not. If its valid you simply print out true else print out false. I'm about 95% done with my code, but I'm having trouble with traversing the 2D Array diagonally. I want to be able to check diagonally NE,NW,SE,SW but I keep getting array out of bounds on my code. I know why I keep getting it I just don't know how to fix it. I'm looking for some guidance on how to fix this issue. Here's my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class nQueensMod {

public static int r,c;
public static int[][]board;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    r = in.nextInt();
    c = in.nextInt();
    board = new int[r][c];
    for(int board_i=0; board_i < r; board_i++){
        for(int board_j=0; board_j < c; board_j++){
            board[board_i][board_j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(solve(board,0,0));
}

   public static boolean solve(int[][]board, int row, int col)
   {
       if(row >= r )
         return true;

        if(board[row][col] == 1)
        {
              if(validRows(row,col) && validCols(col,row))
              {
                 if(move(row,col))
                    return true;
              }

          /*    
              if(validRows(row,col) && validCols(col,row) && validDiagonal(row,col))
              {
                 if(move(row,col))
                    return true;
              }
          */   
        }

           else
           {
              if(move(row,col))
                 return true;
           }

        return false;
   }

   public static boolean validRows(int row, int col)
   {
      for (int i = col + 1; i < r; i++)
      {
        if (board[row][i] == 1)
         {
           return false;
         }
       }

       return true;
   }

   public static boolean validCols(int cols, int row)
   {
      for (int i = row + 1; i < c; i++)
      {
        if (board[i][cols] == 1)
         {
           return false;
         }
       }

       return true;
   }

/*      
   public static boolean validDiagonal(int row, int cols)
   {
      for (int i = 1; i < c; i++)
      {

        if (
              //checks SE
              board[row + i][cols + i] == 1 ||
              //checks SW
              board[row + i][cols - i] == 1 ||
              //checks NE
              board[row - i][cols + i] == 1 ||
              //checks NW
              board[row - i][cols - i] == 1
            )

              return false; 
       }

       return true;
   }
*/      
   public static boolean move(int row,int col)
   {
        if(col < board.length - 1)
           return solve(board,row, col + 1);

           else
              return solve(board,row + 1, 0);
   }
 }
```

I commented out the actual validDiagonal method because that's what I tried but I keep getting the array out of bounds exception. That's the part I need help in.
Here is a sample of the input

```
4 4 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

and Output

```
True
```

This is the error I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at nQueensMod.validDiagonal(nQueensMod.java:88)
at nQueensMod.solve(nQueensMod.java:40)
at nQueensMod.move(nQueensMod.java:108)
at nQueensMod.solve(nQueensMod.java:50)
at nQueensMod.main(nQueensMod.java:23)
```

This is my first time posting on here so I hope I posted the question the right way. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger? What did you find?  Why didn't you include the stack trace in your post? Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes I have used my debugger, it says it goes out of bound (-1) when it hits the first 1 on row[0] col[1]. I know this happens because when  board[row - 1][cols + 1] == 1 is called row is already at 0 therefore, 0 - 1 = -1 which will mean that's the array out of bounds exception. Like I stated in my question I know what the problem is I just need guidance on how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works.  We are not going to rewrite your code to handle boundary conditions, that's something you will need to tackle yourself.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to "rewrite" my code for me. Not sure where you saw that in my entire post. I'm asking what can I do to fix it. You don't have to write out the code for it, I just need suggestions on possible fixes.

Comment: Here is the suggestion that you need: check that row, cols +- 1 is within bounds BEFORE you do the indexing.  Anything more than that and we are effectively writing code for you.

Comment: Thank you! @StephenC I appreciate your feedback, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if your indices are in range before you access the array.

I'll give you a hint,

```
// for NW
if (row-i>0 && col-i>0 && board[row - 1][cols - 1] == 1) 
    return true
```

Do you see why there is an IndexOutOfBoundException?

Comment: Oh! ok got it! It will return false though due to  board[row - 1][cols - 1] == 1. I wasn't sure how to actually check if it was out of bounds first but this makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: yep, this goes for any index access. Just check if the index lies in the range before you make the access.

Comment: Got it! I appreciate your help. I was able to adjust all the checks because of that and now my program runs like a charm. Thanks again!